# Extract a certain pattern string from the text by R

Tags: r, string, subset

I have a column of texts look like below:

```
str1 = "ABCID 123456789 is what I'm looking for, could you help me to check this Item's status?"
```

I want to use `gsub` function in R to extract `"ABCID 123456789"` from there. The number might change with different numbers, but `ABCID` is a constant. Can someone know the solution with that please? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract` to select the fixed word followed by space and one or more numbers (`\\d+`)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(df1$col1, "ABCID \\d+")
```

If there are multiple instances, use `str_extract_all`

```
str_extract_all(df1$col1, "ABCID \\d+")
```

NOTE: The OP states that to extract `"ABCID 123456789"` from there

Answer (score 1):

Match the beginning of string (^) leading letters (ABCID), a space, digits (\d+) and everything else (.*) and replace it all with the captured portion, i.e. the portion within parentheses.  Note that we want to use `sub`, not `gsub`, here because there is only one substitution.

```
sub("^(ABCID \\d+).*", "\\1", str1)
## [1] "ABCID 123456789"
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number has constant length (9) you could you use *positive lookbehind*:

```
sub("(?<=ABCID \\d{9}).*", "", str1, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "ABCID 123456789"
```